# Parsing error: Unexpected Token : after $or

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The exercise to create have a web app that has the user enter their voter id and select a district number. It then shows all statewide and local election races.  Statewide has a district number of 0 and the locals are listed with a specific district number of 1 through 6.  when using the .find function it works perfectly for just local and just statewide but when using $or to do both I get a "Parsing error: Unexpected Token :" at line 55.  I have mongo, monogodb, mongoose, jquery, express, express-handlebars, and body parser installed.

```
const express = require('express');

let app = express();

let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( {extended: false} ) );

// Mongoose options
const options = { server: {socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1} } };

// Set up first mongoose connection
let mongoose1 = require('mongoose');
let db1 = mongoose1.createConnection('mongodb://ballotRO:XooRqtLAxe9ZKK@ds143953.mlab.com:43953/project5', options);
let Race = require('./models/race.js')(db1);

// Set up second mongoose connection
let mongoose2 = require('mongoose');
let db2 = mongoose2.createConnection('mongodb://disuser:RqCRfwUck5B7jYV@ds121192.mlab.com:21192/project5-results', options);
let Vote = require('./models/vote.js')(db2);

// Open the connections
db1.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db1.once('open', function() { console.log("db1 connected"); });

db2.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db2.once('open', function() { console.log("db2 connected"); });


// set up handlebars view engine
let handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
    .create({ defaultLayout:'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});

// Get the appliacable races and then render the ballot
// expects a form submission witha district and voterId
app.post('/ballot', function(req, res) {

    // Make sure the form contains a district and a voter id

    if(req.body && req.body.district && req.body.voterId) {

        const districtInt = parseInt(req.body.district);

        Race.find($or : [{districts: 0}, {districts: districtInt}]).then(function(races) {
            res.render("ballot", {
                voterId: req.body.voterId,
                district: districtInt,
                races: races,
            });
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/");
        });

    } else {

        res.redirect("/");
    }

});


app.post("/vote", function(req, res) {

    if(req.body.voterId) {
        console.log(req.body);

        const votes = Object.assign({}, req.body);
        delete votes.voterId;
        delete votes.disctrict;

        new Vote({
            voterid: req.body.voterId,
            district: req.body.district,
            votes: votes
        }).save().then(function(savedVote) {

        });

        res.redirect("/");
    }
});

// 404 catch-all handler (middleware)
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});

// 500 error handler (middleware)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log( 'Express started on http://localhost:' +
    app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.' );
});
```

Comment: `$or : [{districts: 0}, {districts: districtInt}]` isnt valid syntax, did you mean to make an object with `$or` as a key? eg `{$or: [{districts: 0}, {districts: districtInt}]}`, [the format is on the documentation page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Comment: $or is a mongodb search query that looks for both values https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: Yes I know I linked the same page, you didn't wrap your `$or` part in `{}` which would make it an object which that page shows the correct syntax

Comment: Thank you!  I am an idiot for not noticing that